# Most efficient way to display php css property

Tags: php, css

I am curious as to the correct way to use dynamic css properties. I have variables that if included are displayed in the dynamic css stylesheet.

If I have dynamic css as so

```
body {
    background:<?php global $data; echo $data['body_background'];?>;
    background-image:url(<?php global $data; echo $data['body_background_background']; ?>);
}
```

Am I best using `if statements` before or letting it echo out a blank css statement if it is empty?
For example, if there is no value it would display

```
body {
    background:;
    background-image:url();
}
```

Am i best including it an `if statements` so it doesn't display anything?. For example:

```
if (!empty($data['body_background'])) { 
background:<?php global $data; echo $data['body_background'];?>;
}
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: seperate file but is within style tags. Overrides the original css.

Comment: Efficiency is not an issue here. You're talking about microseconds either way. It's definitely nice (and possibly also, required? Not sure off the top of my head) to not show empty properties at all, though.

Comment: For generation of dynamic CSS you might want to look into [LESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LESS_(stylesheet_language)) or [Sass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_(stylesheet_language)) unless you intend to regenerate the CSS on each request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to streamline the `if` statment.

```
body{
 <?php echo (empty($data['body_background']))?'':'background:'.$data['body_background'].';'; ?>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is all [Macaroni code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code#Macaroni_code). My suggestions are:

- Consider using some templating engines (Smarty, Twig, Mustache, Handlebars, etc) if possible, then it will look much more clear when read.
- Avoid using globals.
- If you still want/need to use php, then use ternary operator as it's suggested in the other answers.
- If your code is running on php >= 5.4 or short_open_tag is supposed to be enabled, then you can replace `<?php echo` by `<?=`
- Make the code explicitly set all the attributes before using them to avoid empty values.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion for you: Implement some kind of stylesheet generator that compiles the variables into a CSS-only file that can then be included. I can't really imagine a practical situation in which the style variables change every request.

Regarding the code style: global is a relict from PHP 4 times and shouldn't be used anymore.

As for your specific question:
Use an if statement to check if the specific array value is filled in the first place. You could do it in the following way.

```
body{
    <?php echo (empty($data['body_background']) ? '' : 'background:' . $data['body_background'] . ';'); ?>
}
```

Comment: `global` is used to include variables outside a function into it. It has no use inside `if` statements unless they also are inside a function. The reason against using `global` is that it couples the code very tightly and not because some people consider it antiquated.

Comment: I know what global is for and it is antiquated at the same time, because with the object model of PHP 5 such a way of coding is no longer necessary. With PHP5 there are object variables or class variables which can be used within a method (plus the superglobals, but they are another story) but no other type of variables. A function outside of a class should be independent from it's location and therefore global is bad practice in several ways.